# Set margin between sent and received messages in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on a chat app and want to add an extra margin between sent and received messages which however is not between 2 sent or 2 received messages. My solution is currently sometimes adding margin incorrectly. It's always adding margin between a sent and received messages but it's also sometimes adding margin between 2 sent or 2 received messages and sometimes it adds margin when I scroll to a message, even though it wasn't there before (images at the bottom)

MessageAdapter.Java:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    public MessageAdapter(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(MessagesBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        boolean sent = messages.get(position).isSent();
        String currentMessageContent = messages.get(position).getMessage();
        String currentMessageTime = messages.get(position).getTime();

        if (sent)
        {
            holder.messagesReceivedLayout.getRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.messagesSentLayout.getRoot().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.messagesSentLayout.messageSentTextContent.setText(currentMessageContent);
            holder.messagesSentLayout.messageSentTextTime.setText(currentMessageTime);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.messagesSentLayout.getRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.messagesReceivedLayout.getRoot().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.messagesReceivedLayout.messageReceivedTextContent.setText(currentMessageContent);
            holder.messagesReceivedLayout.messageReceivedTextTime.setText(currentMessageTime);
        }

        if (position > 0)
        {
            if (messages.get(position - 1).isSent() != sent)
            {
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) holder.messagesReceivedLayout.getRoot().getRootView().getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.topMargin = 80;
                holder.messagesReceivedLayout.getRoot().getRootView().setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        MessageSentBinding messagesSentLayout;
        MessageReceivedBinding messagesReceivedLayout;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull MessagesBinding itemView) {
            super(itemView.getRoot());

            messagesSentLayout = itemView.messagesSentLayout;
            messagesReceivedLayout = itemView.messagesReceivedLayout;
        }
    }
}
```

messages.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/messages_sent_layout"
        layout="@layout/message_sent"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/messages_received_layout"
        layout="@layout/message_received"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

message_received.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/message_received_bg_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/message_received_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/message_received_text_time"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/message_received_text_content"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_received_text_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dm_sans"
        android:text="Sample Text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/message_received_bg_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/message_received_bg_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_received_text_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dm_sans_medium"
        android:text="12:02"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#A9A9A9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/message_received_text_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/message_received_bg_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/message_received_text_content"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.12" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

message_sent.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/message_sent_bg_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/message_sent_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/message_sent_text_time"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/message_sent_text_content"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_sent_text_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dm_sans"
        android:text="Sample Text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/message_sent_bg_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/message_sent_bg_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_sent_text_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="12:02"
        android:textColor="#A9A9A9"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dm_sans_medium"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.15"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/message_sent_bg_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/message_sent_bg_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/message_sent_text_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_sent_tick"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="1.5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/read_message_tick"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/message_sent_text_time"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/message_sent_text_time"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/message_sent_text_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/message_sent_text_time" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Chat.java:

```
public class Chat extends Fragment {

    private MaterialButton sendButton;
    private EditText inputText;
    private MaterialCardView bottomNavBg;
    private FragmentChatBinding binding;

    private List<Message> messageList;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentChatBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        inputText = binding.inputBottomChat;
        bottomNavBg = binding.barChatBottom;
        sendButton = binding.sendBottomChat;

        getArgs();

        messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        addMessages();
        clearFocus();
        sendMessage();
    }

    private void clearFocus()
    {
        View.OnClickListener clearFocusListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                inputText.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        };

        binding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(clearFocusListener);
        binding.recyclerView.setOnClickListener(clearFocusListener);
    }

    private void addMessages()
    {
        messageList.add(new Message("Hello, how are you?", "12:02", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("I'm fine?", "12:03", false));
        messageList.add(new Message("What are you doing?", "12:03", false));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf?", "12:03", false));
        messageList.add(new Message("Nothing", "12:04", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", false));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", false));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", false));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", true));
        messageList.add(new Message("dfslkfjsdlkfjs dsljkfns,dkfj sdflksjfddlsk dsfkjfflkdsjfsdfj sdflksjdfldskjf", "12:05", true));
        loadMessages();
    }

    private void loadMessages()
    {
        MessageAdapter messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messageList);
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity());
        manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        binding.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
    }
```

Images:
[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common error with using *RecyclerView* is to set a value in the item view when some condition is met but not setting the value when the condition is not met. Remember that view holders are reused (recycled) by the *RecyclerView*.

Your problem code is the following:

```
 if (position > 0)
        {
            if (messages.get(position - 1).isSent() != sent)
            {
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) holder.messagesReceivedLayout.getRoot().getRootView().getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.topMargin = 80;
                holder.messagesReceivedLayout.getRoot().getRootView().setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        }
```

You will always need to address the margin each time since you can't assume that it has the original value as defined in the layout file.